# UIImageView to UIImage

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage

I have UIImageView contains static image, I want to get this image and set it under UIImage variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: UIImage* image = imageView.image;

Answer (score 13):

```
UIImageView *imageView = ... // Set from somewhere

UIImage *image = imageView.image; // Get the UIImage.
UIImage *otherImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]; // Load another image.
imageView.image = otherImage; // Change in the image in your UIImageView.
```

[UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) at developer.apple.com